# Fill in formula in every other cell with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need every other column to have a network url to collect values from a different `.xlsx`file. My code fills the correct cells with a simple formula, i.e. `"=1+5"`, but not with the network url string `myString`. I get the error

> Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

on the line `Cells(thisRow, 2 * i).Formula = myString & a & "$23"`. See the example code below

```
Function Col_Letter(lngCol As Long) As String
Dim vArr
vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")
Col_Letter = vArr(0)
End Function

Sub fillThePaths()
    Dim Filepath, Filename, myString, a As String
    Dim i, thisRow, startColumn, startYear, spanYear As Integer

    Filepath = "\\myPath\"
    Filename = "myFile.xlsm"
    thisRow = 3
    startColumn = 5
    startYear = 2018
    spanYear = 2040 - startYear
    myString = "='" & Filepath & "[" & Filename & "]Totalresultat'!"

    For i = 1 To spanYear
        a = Col_Letter(i + 2)
        Cells(thisRow, 2 * i).Formula = myString & a & "$23"
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Does the formula string work if you enter it into a cell manually?

Comment: I always helps if you tell us what line is giving you the error.

Comment: Ah, sorry MatthewD, updating now.

Comment: I don't get the error while executing this. could be cause I miss the referenced files. You could try to qualify the error line with a preceding `ActiveSheet.` But since another line is using `Cells`, too, I guess that won't work :/

Comment: @Rory thank you for that simple question. It turns out the url I made had a minor typing error. Damn, all those hours...

Comment: You also may want to adjust this line `Dim i, thisRow, startColumn, startYear, spanYear As Integer`. I assume that you want to define all these variables as Type - Integer, but the way it is written, only `spanYear` is actually set as Type - Integer. All the rest are Variant. If you want all to be Integer, you need to write `Dim i as Integer, thisRow as Integer ...`

Comment: @Holene : Is your problem solved? Was it only the typo in URL?

Comment: @R3uK Yes, that is sadly true. Well, I hadn't really expected a typo in the path to kill the entire macro, but I guess I could handle that with some some `catch` statements or similar

Comment: Don't worry, silly mistakes happen to everyone! I've got my own share of them too! ;)